# Restore data only from Time Machine

Tags: mac-osx, mac, backup-restoration, time-machine

I'll have following scenario:
1, I use Time Machine to backup my data from my Mac, I excluded Applications folder and some others, so I really backup data only
2, I'll buy new Snow Leopard
3, I want totally clean install, so when installing Snow Leopard I'll erase disk-do clean install
4, Then I want to restore data ONLY from my Time Machine backup, basically just data from my home folder(except excluded folders which obviously can't be restored), latest version.

I'm using Mac for just few months so I've never done this. Can you please provide me steps to do? Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I don't mind losing system settings, installed applications etc. I really want totally clean install and my backed up data. I'll install all application manually later.

Answer (score 3):

When you install Snow Leopard you will be given the option of migrating your files and such from a variety of locations: (eg. another Mac, another partition, **a Time Machine Backup**, or just another startup disk). This will bring back nearly everything from your home folder (Caches are usually not copied) onto your new partition and you're good to go.

If you need to do this after an install you can run it manually using Migration Assistant.app (found in the Utilities folder).

Comment: Thanks, so I can be 100% sure that I will be able to restore my data from time machine disk, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you backup everything on your old Mac with Time Machine (including /Applications as this is the defautl configuration, and those tend to work best) and then you use the Migration Assistant on the new machine to pull in your old user from the Time Machine backup.

Easy, and simple.